# Appending strings in batch has limit in bytes for output csv?

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

My problem is simple but somehow I don't get my result. I have a .txt file with 441 columns as a header and another .txt with the values (440 columns) but I want to include a string in the beggining of this file. When I output the edited file with the values, the number of columns is showing only 112 columns with the string echoed at the beggining. This is a problem of reading operator <, or this operation is limited in bytes, or characters?

**What I Did**

```
> head.txt (
   echo Id,LH_LTP_tractNum,LH_LTP_voxelNum,LH_LTP_FA_Min,LH_LTP_FA_Avg,LH_LTP_FA_Med,LH_LTP_FA_Max,LH_LTP_FA_Std,LH_LTP_AD_Min,LH_LTP_AD_Avg,LH_LTP_AD_Med,LH_LTP_AD_Max,LH_LTP_AD_Std,LH_LTP_RD_Min,LH_LTP_RD_Avg,LH_LTP_RD_Med,LH_LTP_RD_Max,LH_LTP_RD_Std,LH_LTP_MD_Min,LH_LTP_MD_Avg,LH_LTP_MD_Med,LH_LTP_MD_Max,LH_LTP_MD_Std,LH_LSTG_tractNum,LH_LSTG_voxelNum,LH_LSTG_FA_Min,LH_LSTG_FA_Avg,LH_LSTG_FA_Med,LH_LSTG_FA_Max,LH_LSTG_FA_Std,LH_LSTG_AD_Min,LH_LSTG_AD_Avg,LH_LSTG_AD_Med,LH_LSTG_AD_Max,LH_LSTG_AD_Std,LH_LSTG_RD_Min,LH_LSTG_RD_Avg,LH_LSTG_RD_Med,LH_LSTG_RD_Max,LH_LSTG_RD_Std,LH_LSTG_MD_Min,LH_LSTG_MD_Avg,LH_LSTG_MD_Med,LH_LSTG_MD_Max,LH_LSTG_MD_Std,LH_LTTG_tractNum,LH_LTTG_voxelNum,LH_LTTG_FA_Min,LH_LTTG_FA_Avg,LH_LTTG_FA_Med,LH_LTTG_FA_Max,LH_LTTG_FA_Std,LH_LTTG_AD_Min,LH_LTTG_AD_Avg,LH_LTTG_AD_Med,LH_LTTG_AD_Max,LH_LTTG_AD_Std,LH_LTTG_RD_Min,LH_LTTG_RD_Avg,LH_LTTG_RD_Med,LH_LTTG_RD_Max,LH_LTTG_RD_Std,LH_LTTG_MD_Min,LH_LTTG_MD_Avg,LH_LTTG_MD_Med,LH_LTTG_MD_Max,LH_LTTG_MD_Std,LH_LMTG_tractNum,LH_LMTG_voxelNum,LH_LMTG_FA_Min,LH_LMTG_FA_Avg,LH_LMTG_FA_Med,LH_LMTG_FA_Max,LH_LMTG_FA_Std,LH_LMTG_AD_Min,LH_LMTG_AD_Avg,LH_LMTG_AD_Med,LH_LMTG_AD_Max,LH_LMTG_AD_Std,LH_LMTG_RD_Min,LH_LMTG_RD_Avg,LH_LMTG_RD_Med,LH_LMTG_RD_Max,LH_LMTG_RD_Std,LH_LMTG_MD_Min,LH_LMTG_MD_Avg,LH_LMTG_MD_Med,LH_LMTG_MD_Max,LH_LMTG_MD_Std,LH_LITG_tractNum,LH_LITG_voxelNum,LH_LITG_FA_Min,LH_LITG_FA_Avg,LH_LITG_FA_Med,LH_LITG_FA_Max,LH_LITG_FA_Std,LH_LITG_AD_Min,LH_LITG_AD_Avg,LH_LITG_AD_Med,LH_LITG_AD_Max,LH_LITG_AD_Std,LH_LITG_RD_Min,LH_LITG_RD_Avg,LH_LITG_RD_Med,LH_LITG_RD_Max,LH_LITG_RD_Std,LH_LITG_MD_Min,LH_LITG_MD_Avg,LH_LITG_MD_Med,LH_LITG_MD_Max,LH_LITG_MD_Std,RH_RTP_tractNum,RH_RTP_voxelNum,RH_RTP_FA_Min,RH_RTP_FA_Avg,RH_RTP_FA_Med,RH_RTP_FA_Max,RH_RTP_FA_Std,RH_RTP_AD_Min,RH_RTP_AD_Avg,RH_RTP_AD_Med,RH_RTP_AD_Max,RH_RTP_AD_Std,RH_RTP_RD_Min,RH_RTP_RD_Avg,RH_RTP_RD_Med,RH_RTP_RD_Max,RH_RTP_RD_Std,RH_RTP_MD_Min,RH_RTP_MD_Avg,RH_RTP_MD_Med,RH_RTP_MD_Max,RH_RTP_MD_Std,RH_RSTG_tractNum,RH_RSTG_voxelNum,RH_RSTG_FA_Min,RH_RSTG_FA_Avg,RH_RSTG_FA_Med,RH_RSTG_FA_Max,RH_RSTG_FA_Std,RH_RSTG_AD_Min,RH_RSTG_AD_Avg,RH_RSTG_AD_Med,RH_RSTG_AD_Max,RH_RSTG_AD_Std,RH_RSTG_RD_Min,RH_RSTG_RD_Avg,RH_RSTG_RD_Med,RH_RSTG_RD_Max,RH_RSTG_RD_Std,RH_RSTG_MD_Min,RH_RSTG_MD_Avg,RH_RSTG_MD_Med,RH_RSTG_MD_Max,RH_RSTG_MD_Std,RH_RTTG_tractNum,RH_RTTG_voxelNum,RH_RTTG_FA_Min,RH_RTTG_FA_Avg,RH_RTTG_FA_Med,RH_RTTG_FA_Max,RH_RTTG_FA_Std,RH_RTTG_AD_Min,RH_RTTG_AD_Avg,RH_RTTG_AD_Med,RH_RTTG_AD_Max,RH_RTTG_AD_Std,RH_RTTG_RD_Min,RH_RTTG_RD_Avg,RH_RTTG_RD_Med,RH_RTTG_RD_Max,RH_RTTG_RD_Std,RH_RTTG_MD_Min,RH_RTTG_MD_Avg,RH_RTTG_MD_Med,RH_RTTG_MD_Max,RH_RTTG_MD_Std,RH_RMTG_tractNum,RH_RMTG_voxelNum,RH_RMTG_FA_Min,RH_RMTG_FA_Avg,RH_RMTG_FA_Med,RH_RMTG_FA_Max,RH_RMTG_FA_Std,RH_RMTG_AD_Min,RH_RMTG_AD_Avg,RH_RMTG_AD_Med,RH_RMTG_AD_Max,RH_RMTG_AD_Std,RH_RMTG_RD_Min,RH_RMTG_RD_Avg,RH_RMTG_RD_Med,RH_RMTG_RD_Max,RH_RMTG_RD_Std,RH_RMTG_MD_Min,RH_RMTG_MD_Avg,RH_RMTG_MD_Med,RH_RMTG_MD_Max,RH_RMTG_MD_Std,RH_RITG_tractNum,RH_RITG_voxelNum,RH_RITG_FA_Min,RH_RITG_FA_Avg,RH_RITG_FA_Med,RH_RITG_FA_Max,RH_RITG_FA_Std,RH_RITG_AD_Min,RH_RITG_AD_Avg,RH_RITG_AD_Med,RH_RITG_AD_Max,RH_RITG_AD_Std,RH_RITG_RD_Min,RH_RITG_RD_Avg,RH_RITG_RD_Med,RH_RITG_RD_Max,RH_RITG_RD_Std,RH_RITG_MD_Min,RH_RITG_MD_Avg,RH_RITG_MD_Med,RH_RITG_MD_Max,RH_RITG_MD_Std,LH_RTP_tractNum,LH_RTP_voxelNum,LH_RTP_FA_Min,LH_RTP_FA_Avg,LH_RTP_FA_Med,LH_RTP_FA_Max,LH_RTP_FA_Std,LH_RTP_AD_Min,LH_RTP_AD_Avg,LH_RTP_AD_Med,LH_RTP_AD_Max,LH_RTP_AD_Std,LH_RTP_RD_Min,LH_RTP_RD_Avg,LH_RTP_RD_Med,LH_RTP_RD_Max,LH_RTP_RD_Std,LH_RTP_MD_Min,LH_RTP_MD_Avg,LH_RTP_MD_Med,LH_RTP_MD_Max,LH_RTP_MD_Std,LH_RSTG_tractNum,LH_RSTG_voxelNum,LH_RSTG_FA_Min,LH_RSTG_FA_Avg,LH_RSTG_FA_Med,LH_RSTG_FA_Max,LH_RSTG_FA_Std,LH_RSTG_AD_Min,LH_RSTG_AD_Avg,LH_RSTG_AD_Med,LH_RSTG_AD_Max,LH_RSTG_AD_Std,LH_RSTG_RD_Min,LH_RSTG_RD_Avg,LH_RSTG_RD_Med,LH_RSTG_RD_Max,LH_RSTG_RD_Std,LH_RSTG_MD_Min,LH_RSTG_MD_Avg,LH_RSTG_MD_Med,LH_RSTG_MD_Max,LH_RSTG_MD_Std,LH_RTTG_tractNum,LH_RTTG_voxelNum,LH_RTTG_FA_Min,LH_RTTG_FA_Avg,LH_RTTG_FA_Med,LH_RTTG_FA_Max,LH_RTTG_FA_Std,LH_RTTG_AD_Min,LH_RTTG_AD_Avg,LH_RTTG_AD_Med,LH_RTTG_AD_Max,LH_RTTG_AD_Std,LH_RTTG_RD_Min,LH_RTTG_RD_Avg,LH_RTTG_RD_Med,LH_RTTG_RD_Max,LH_RTTG_RD_Std,LH_RTTG_MD_Min,LH_RTTG_MD_Avg,LH_RTTG_MD_Med,LH_RTTG_MD_Max,LH_RTTG_MD_Std,LH_RMTG_tractNum,LH_RMTG_voxelNum,LH_RMTG_FA_Min,LH_RMTG_FA_Avg,LH_RMTG_FA_Med,LH_RMTG_FA_Max,LH_RMTG_FA_Std,LH_RMTG_AD_Min,LH_RMTG_AD_Avg,LH_RMTG_AD_Med,LH_RMTG_AD_Max,LH_RMTG_AD_Std,LH_RMTG_RD_Min,LH_RMTG_RD_Avg,LH_RMTG_RD_Med,LH_RMTG_RD_Max,LH_RMTG_RD_Std,LH_RMTG_MD_Min,LH_RMTG_MD_Avg,LH_RMTG_MD_Med,LH_RMTG_MD_Max,LH_RMTG_MD_Std,LH_RITG_tractNum,LH_RITG_voxelNum,LH_RITG_FA_Min,LH_RITG_FA_Avg,LH_RITG_FA_Med,LH_RITG_FA_Max,LH_RITG_FA_Std,LH_RITG_AD_Min,LH_RITG_AD_Avg,LH_RITG_AD_Med,LH_RITG_AD_Max,LH_RITG_AD_Std,LH_RITG_RD_Min,LH_RITG_RD_Avg,LH_RITG_RD_Med,LH_RITG_RD_Max,LH_RITG_RD_Std,LH_RITG_MD_Min,LH_RITG_MD_Avg,LH_RITG_MD_T1_Med,LH_RITG_MD_Max,LH_RITG_MD_Std,RH_LTP_tractNum,RH_LTP_voxelNum,RH_LTP_FA_Min,RH_LTP_FA_Avg,RH_LTP_FA_Med,RH_LTP_FA_Max,RH_LTP_FA_Std,RH_LTP_AD_Min,RH_LTP_AD_Avg,RH_LTP_AD_Med,RH_LTP_AD_Max,RH_LTP_AD_Std,RH_LTP_RD_Min,RH_LTP_RD_Avg,RH_LTP_RD_Med,RH_LTP_RD_Max,RH_LTP_RD_Std,RH_LTP_MD_Min,RH_LTP_MD_Avg,RH_LTP_MD_Med,RH_LTP_MD_Max,RH_LTP_MD_Std,RH_LSTG_tractNum,RH_LSTG_voxelNum,RH_LSTG_FA_Min,RH_LSTG_FA_Avg,RH_LSTG_FA_Med,RH_LSTG_FA_Max,RH_LSTG_FA_Std,RH_LSTG_AD_Min,RH_LSTG_AD_Avg,RH_LSTG_AD_Med,RH_LSTG_AD_Max,RH_LSTG_AD_Std,RH_LSTG_RD_Min,RH_LSTG_RD_Avg,RH_LSTG_RD_Med,RH_LSTG_RD_Max,RH_LSTG_RD_Std,RH_LSTG_MD_Min,RH_LSTG_MD_Avg,RH_LSTG_MD_Med,RH_LSTG_MD_Max,RH_LSTG_MD_Std,RH_LTTG_tractNum,RH_LTTG_voxelNum,RH_LTTG_FA_Min,RH_LTTG_FA_Avg,RH_LTTG_FA_Med,RH_LTTG_FA_T1_Max,RH_LTTG_FA_Std,RH_LTTG_AD_Min,RH_LTTG_AD_Avg,RH_LTTG_AD_Med,RH_LTTG_AD_Max,RH_LTTG_AD_Std,RH_LTTG_RD_Min,RH_LTTG_RD_Avg,RH_LTTG_RD_Med,RH_LTTG_RD_Max,RH_LTTG_RD_Std,RH_LTTG_MD_Min,RH_LTTG_MD_Avg,RH_LTTG_MD_Med,RH_LTTG_MD_Max,RH_LTTG_MD_Std,RH_LMTG_tractNum,RH_LMTG_voxelNum,RH_LMTG_FA_Min,RH_LMTG_FA_Avg,RH_LMTG_FA_Med,RH_LMTG_FA_Max,RH_LMTG_FA_Std,RH_LMTG_AD_Min,RH_LMTG_AD_Avg,RH_LMTG_AD_Med,RH_LMTG_AD_Max,RH_LMTG_AD_Std,RH_LMTG_RD_Min,RH_LMTG_RD_Avg,RH_LMTG_RD_Med,RH_LMTG_RD_Max,RH_LMTG_RD_Std,RH_LMTG_MD_Min,RH_LMTG_MD_Avg,RH_LMTG_MD_Med,RH_LMTG_MD_Max,RH_LMTG_MD_Std,RH_LITG_tractNum,RH_LITG_voxelNum,RH_LITG_FA_Min,RH_LITG_FA_Avg,RH_LITG_FA_Med,RH_LITG_FA_Max,RH_LITG_FA_Std,RH_LITG_AD_Min,RH_LITG_AD_Avg,RH_LITG_AD_Med,RH_LITG_AD_Max,RH_LITG_AD_Std,RH_LITG_RD_Min,RH_LITG_RD_Avg,RH_LITG_RD_Med,RH_LITG_RD_Max,RH_LITG_RD_Std,RH_LITG_MD_Min,RH_LITG_MD_Avg,RH_LITG_MD_Med,RH_LITG_MD_Max,RH_LITG_MD_Std,
)


set /p "values=" < "values.csv"
> newvalues.csv (
   echo 1,%values%,
)

type newvalues.csv >> head.csv
```

I've created a simple file for test porpuse and I did not have any problem with the same code.

Comment: `set /p` has a [character limit of 1024](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2160).

Comment: TXT files do not have columns, and neither do CSV files. You have a `.csv` extension file with records consisting of comma separated field values and a `.txt` extension file consisting of a single line of comma separated string data.

Comment: @Stephan Is there another way to read the file and print it with the string in the example?

Comment: technically no, but you can do it in another way - see my answer

Comment: What research and testing have you done in the ten minutes since @Stephan commented? Please do not treat this site as a one to one personal programming tutor service.

Comment: @Stephan Oh I didn't see the link I will see, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the file with `set /p`, you truncate your line to 1024 characters (hard limit of `set /p`)

Use another approach: write the short "preface" to the new file (without a linefeed) and add the original file:

```
>newhead.txt set /p "=1," <nul
>>newhead.txt type head.txt
```

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused, what is your newhead.txt? Is it the row for the values or the header?

Comment: sorry, `newhead.txt` is your `newvalues.csv` (I guess you figured it out already)